# Host beta app on subdomain through Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

We have a landing site on Heroku with a user signup form. In the DNS, the apex points to `www.`, which points to Heroku.

We'd like to put up a beta site, using the `beta` subdomain. For now the beta site should be separate from the main site, but they should use the same database, as we'd like to merge the beta site into the main site once it's out of beta.

For example, [asana.com](http://asana.com) points to their info site, while [app.asana.com](http://app.asana.com) points to the app.

Is there a way to tell which subdomain a request came from and redirect accordingly, or a way to manage and eventually merge two apps on Heroku? Is this something that requires two apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need two separate applications for this.
Take a look at [Request-Based Constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) from the Rails Routing guide.

Basically, you would have something like this :

```
root "launch#index", :constraints => {:subdomain => "www"}

constraints :subdomain => "beta" do
  # All your app's routes
end
```